# jQuery custom function not returning as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, word-wrap

I'm attempting to create a jQuery version of php's wordwrap function -- I asked an earlier question about this and was directed to [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/wordwrap-for-javascript/) javascript function which does exactly what I'm looking for, except that I can't get it to play friendly with jQuery -- mostly I think out of ignorance.

I decided to try to adapt the code I was provided with into a jQuery plugin -- for fun and because I can't find anything to do what I want and because I figured it would be a good learning experience but I can't get it working--

here's the original javascript:

```
function wordwrap( str, width, brk, cut ) {

    brk = brk || '\n';
    width = width || 75;
    cut = cut || false;

    if (!str) { return str; }

    var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

    return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join( brk );

}
```

And then my jQuery -- which I think is probably all wrong:

```
  $.fn.wordwrap = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      'brk': '<br>',
      'width': '5',
      'cut': 'false'
    }, options);

    var regex = '.{1,' +settings.width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (settings.cut ? '|.{' +settings.width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

    return this.html(function(i, html) {
      return text.html(RegExp(regex, 'g')).join(settings.brk);
    });
```

I have limited experience with plugin-authoring. I've read through the jQuery guide at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring and I feel like I'm doing everything properly but it doesn't do anything when called on an element, for example:

```
$('#foo').wordwrap({'width' : '25'});
```

I'm not getting any errors on chrome web inspector but nothing happens on my page either...

*I believe the problem lies in the return string at the end of the function -- I am guessing that I am not doing something properly down there in order to get the desired output*

Any help greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
GOT IT THANKS!
Here's the final script I'm using:

```
  $.fn.wordwrap = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      'brk': '<br>',
      'width': '75',
      'cut': 'false'
    }, options);

    var regex = '.{1,' +settings.width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (settings.cut ? '|.{' +settings.width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

    return this.html(function(i, html) {
      var match = html.match(RegExp(regex, 'g'));
      if (match != null) {
        return match.join(settings.brk); 
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return text from a jQuery plugin like that, you return the collection you are working on. This makes chaining work.

I think this is what you want...

```
$.fn.wordwrap = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        'brk': '<br>',
        'width': '75',
        'cut': 'false'
    }, options);

    var regex = '.{1,' + settings.width + '}(\\s|$)' + (settings.cut ? '|.{' + settings.width + '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');


    return this.text(function(i, text) {
              return text.match(RegExp(regex, 'g')).join(settings.brk);
           });

};
```

You should also change the `cut` option to default to `false`. Wrapping it in a string just makes things harder. The `width` option should also just be a `Number`.

Comment: this is great -- however i'm getting an error in webinspector now that says "uncaught typeError: cannot call method 'join' of null -- it is working though--however I'm getting <br> as text rather than html -- how would I turn that into a usable piece of html?

Comment: @thomas: If `match()` couldn't match, it will return `null`. You need to deal with that.

Comment: @alex meaning if i call this on all <h1> elements for example, and one of them doesn't match, it will return null? correct?

Comment: @thomas: Nope. See the documentation for `match()`.

Comment: thanks so much! I checked out the match() docs and arrived at the little if statement i added (see my updated question) thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the time to turn it into a plugin based on the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).  You can get it from [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SuFX5/), where you can also test it.  I've also posted it below so you can check it out without having to go to jsfiddle.net.  It supports chaining, and checks to make sure the object this is being applied to has a text property before it attempts wrapping.

```
(function ($) {
    var settings = {
        brk: '<br />',
        width: '75',
        cut: 'false'
    }, methods = {
        init : function( options ) {     
            var regex,
                t = $(this),
                txt = t.text();

            settings = $.extend(settings, options);

            regex = '.{1,' + settings.width + '}(\\s|$)' + (settings.cut ? 
                            '|.{' + settings.width + '}|.+$' : 
                            '|\\S+?(\\s|$)')

            if (txt && txt !== '') {            
                t.html(txt.match(RegExp(regex, 'g')).join(settings.brk));
            }

            return t;
        }
    };

    $.fn.wordwrap = function( method ) {  
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.wordwrap.' );
        }      
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: this is wonderful -- however in order for this to work I'd need to add an ID to each element I want to call it on and I would really prefer not doing that -- currently if I call it on an element by type it will attach every instance of that element as the output, see the update to your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/SuFX5/1/ -- thanks!

Comment: Why the method invocation code when `init` is the only method?

Comment: @alex For extensibility.  However if this is to be the extent of the plugin, the separation is unnecessary.  I like to try to keep my plugins in the same format, so I just stick to this model.